# "Push" for Google Assistant Actions (preferably using API.AI)

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working on an Action that requires some (long) background processing. How do I notify user upon completion?

To make this question generic: How to do "push notification" for Google Assistant Actions, preferably using API.AI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do a push notification through Actions on Google for all Assistant platforms.

From a design perspective, this isn't necessary a good approach. Anything that takes more than a couple of seconds veers away from a "conversation". You may offer to send the reply in an email or via another notification channel.

There are, however, some hints that this will be coming eventually in some form. The Transactions API has a way to [update order information](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/dev-guide#send_order_updates) asynchronously to the user after the initial conversation has ended, but currently this is only in developer preview and only available for the Assistant on Android and iPhone.

Google has indicated that proactive notifications will be coming to the Google Home, but they haven't indicated how (or if or when) this will be available to developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate push notifications using [Action on Google Setup Push notificaiton or daily updates](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates).

Make sure you are doint exact setup as per document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the actions sdk?

Comment: @NiteLordz Maybe not. :|

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for your local home network, you can "talk" to the Assistant, since it's a GoogleCast device.

If this is a general purpose skill there's nothing you can do. You can ask the user to check back for the results "Ok, Google! Ask XYZ if my stuff was ready!". Or alternatively you can send an SMS or an email.